# The configured limit of 1.000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, jhipster

I have a jhipster project and I added some entities.
My services are very slow because this warning message:

> The configured limit of 1.000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph. Severe performance degradation could occur if the sizing operation continues. This can be avoided by setting the CacheManger or Cache <sizeOfPolicy> elements maxDepthExceededBehavior to "abort" or adding stop points with @IgnoreSizeOf annotations. If performance degradation is NOT an issue at the configured limit, raise the limit value using the CacheManager or Cache <sizeOfPolicy> elements maxDepth attribute. For more information, see the Ehcache configuration documentation.

What I can change to increase this limit or to cancel cache in my project?

Comment: Cancelling cache is not what one does usually to speed up things :)

Comment: You need to indicate where you are using caching and on which kind of objects, so that you can understand why you cache such a large graph at once.

Answer (score 10):

Here is what [Ehcache official documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/configuration/cache-size.html) says about *Sizing of cached entries*:

## Sizing of cached entries

---

Elements put in a memory-limited cache will have their memory sizes
measured. The entire Element instance added to the cache is measured,
including key and value, as well as the memory footprint of adding
that instance to internal data structures. Key and value are measured
as object graphs – each reference is followed and the object
reference also measured. This goes on recursively.

Shared references will be measured by each class that references it.
This will result in an overstatement. Shared references should
therefore be ignored.

## Configuration for Limiting the Traversed Object Graph

---

Sizing caches involves traversing object graphs, a process that can be limited with annotations. This process can also be controlled at both the CacheManager and cache levels.

Control how deep the size-of engine can go when sizing on-heap elements by adding the following element at the CacheManager level in  `resources/ehcache.xml`

```
<sizeOfPolicy maxDepth="100" maxDepthExceededBehavior="abort" />
```

This element has the following attributes:

- `maxDepth` which controls how many linked objects can be visited before the size-of engine takes any action. **This attribute is required**.
- `maxDepthExceededBehavior` which specifies what happens when the max depth is exceeded while sizing an object graph. Possible values for this filed are:
- `continue` which forces
  the size-of engine to log a warning and continue the sizing
  operation. If this attribute is not specified, `continue` is the
  behavior used
- `abort` which forces the size-of engine to abort the
  sizing, log a warning, and mark the cache as not correctly tracking
  memory usage. With this setting, `Ehcache.hasAbortedSizeOf()` returns
  `true`

The SizeOf policy can be configured at the cache manager level
(directly under `<ehcache>`) and at the cache level (under `<cache>` or
`<defaultCache>`). The cache policy always overrides the cache manager
one if both are set. **This element has no effect on distributed
caches.**

Answer (score 6):

You can add following tag in your **resources/ehcache.xml** . property ***maxDepthExceededBehavior*=*abort*** avoids from slowing your services. Also you can change the ***maxDepth*** to increase the limit.

```
<sizeOfPolicy maxDepth="1000" maxDepthExceededBehavior="abort" />
```

Comment: I am using ehcache3 and creating cache manager programmatically.how can this field be set programmatically in ehcache 3 in spring boot.?