# Skipped breakpoint because it happened inside debugger evaluation - Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

When I try to pick a breakpoint on any executive line of any method of my project, and I know that this method should be invoked for example 4 times, Intellij skips this breakpoint for 3 times and stops only on the last invocation.
Method example (Endpoint class):

```
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "getRelatedCIs", namespace = "http://www.projectname.com/ws")
public GetRelatedCIsResponse getRelatedCIs(GetRelatedCIs request) throws DataAccessException, WebServiceException {
    GetRelatedCIsResponse response = new GetRelatedCIsResponse();
    PageData page = request.getPageData();
    List<ConfigItemReference> ciRefs = translateCiRefList(request.getCiRef());
    RelatedCiResult relatedCis = configItemService.getRelatedCis(ciRefs, request.getRequestedType(),
            new Page(page.getPageNumber(), page.getPageSize(), page.getTotal()), request.getSort());
    response.getCis().addAll(relatedCis.getCis());
    page.setTotal(relatedCis.getPageInfo().getTotal());
    page.setPageSize(relatedCis.getPageInfo().getPageSize());
    response.setPageData(page);
    System.out.println("****************************INVOCATION***************************" + request.getRequestedType());
    return response;
}
```

Breakpoint is picked on the first line of the method. When program is stopped, there are already printed in console 3 lines ****************************INVOCATION***************************

In the left bottom part of the screen appears green notification:

**Skipped breakpoint at %code reference% because it happened inside debugger evaluation**

But I don't use any Evaluate Expression functionality when I perform debugging.
Also there are my VM options of Run/Debug Configurations:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-Xms256m 
-Xmx1024m 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The problem is described in [IDEA-43728](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-43728) and in the [breakpoints documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-properties).

In short, to avoid it use suspend thread (not all) breakpoint policy.

Comment: The second link is not found

Comment: I have no suspended threads and this happens to me. The entire application is running and I get these yellow messages if I try to break.

Comment: This not works for me, sorry. And I am an Ultimate edition user. I do not think IntelliJ IDE should skip breakpoints when developer explicitly put it in some method. Why would I need breakpoints at all if IDE skips them? In addition to that I would rather prefer to see answer to topic starter question instead of tedious IntelliJ bug track link.

Comment: Didn't work for me, macOS, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.1

Comment: Didn't work for me, macOS 12.5, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.1

Comment: I was getting this in a step out so I can't really configure the breakpoint. Any way in the scenario @Egor?

Answer (score 17):

try disable the 'toString()' object view
[image]

Comment: Didn't work for me, macOS, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.1

Comment: Worked on Win11, IntelliJ Ultimate 2022.1.3.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same, and **disable this** helped me

[image]

Comment: it is the solution, has worked wonderfully for me, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the below checkbox helped me to minimize this error frequency. "Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping - Resume only the current thread" (as per suggestion in a fix https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-43728)

Answer (score 0):

Click on "View breakpoints" (Shift+Cmd+F8) and unselect all