# Stack implementation using LinkedList in java references not working properly

Tags: java, reference, stack

Each time a push operation is called on this stack, the new node is created but the stack just gets null.
Please help me with what is wrong with my code.
I am messing up with reference variables. When a push operation is called from main method, the top gets null each time. I don't know why is this happening.
import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class LinkedListImplStack {

```
public LinkedListImplStack() {
    this.top = null;
}
//Node
private static class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node next;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

// maintain top
private Node top;

//push()
public void push(T data) {
    Node<T> node = new Node(data);
    node.next = top;
     top = node;
}

//pop()
public T pop() {
    if(top == null)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    T toBePopped = (T) top.data;
    top = top.next;
    return toBePopped;
}

//peek()
public T peek() {
    if(top == null)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return (T) top.data;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while(top!=null) {
        s.append(top.data + " -> ");
        top = top.next;
    }
    return s.toString();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedListImplStack myStack = new LinkedListImplStack();
    myStack.push(1);
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(3);
    System.out.println(myStack);
    myStack.pop();
    System.out.println(myStack);
    myStack.push("four");
    System.out.println(myStack);
    System.out.println(myStack.peek());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while(top!=null) {
        s.append(top.data + " -> ");
        top = top.next;
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

When calling `toString()`, you move the member variable `top` pointer along to the end of the stack, effectively `null`ing the stack; make a copy of `top` and iterate over that to solve your problem.

Comment: When i call this method -   myStack.push(1);  Internally toString() method is being called?? Because i haven't called it until i have pushed 3 elements to stack.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij, there is an enable toString() view of an object property, if we disable it, then toString() will be invoked only when we invoke it.
Otherwise toString() is invoked each time a method like stack.push() is being called, which makes my stack null due to the incorrect implementation of my toString() method.

The first answer will help with the understanding.

[Skipped breakpoint because it happened inside debugger evaluation - Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47866398/skipped-breakpoint-because-it-happened-inside-debugger-evaluation-intellij-ide)