# Intellij debugger getting stuck at "collecting data" while testing the application with Wiremock mocks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wiremock

I am developing acceptance tests for an application and mocking all external API calls in WireMock. It is a java (Spring boot) application. In intellIj debugger it gets stuck in break points saying "`Collecting data"` when I try to see the content of a variable or object. If I try to resume the program it shows `waiting until the last debugger command completes` and gets stuck. during this the IntellIj keeps using it's maximum memory.

Note:

1. This question is not similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863400/intellij-debugger-gets-stuck). As over there it is a stand alone application and here it is a web application having it's external API calls being mocked by WireMock, and none of there mentioned answered helped my case.
2. I have installed a few plugins recently and thought they might be the problem so have removed them.
3. I console I am able to see the API calls being made properly as I could see there response coming.
4. I am using IntellIj ultimate edition 2020.2 right now on a Windows 10 system without Admin access.

I have been stuck with this for a while and any help would be useful.

Edit: It got this resolved by [downgrading my IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63621174/6910789).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55913491/intellij-idea-stucks-at-collecting-data-while-debug

Comment: @xingbin I have already seen that. I am not running threads and variables window together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it resolved by downgrading by IntelliJ IDEA to 2020.1.2 from 2020.2

Comment: Do you have JRebel plug-in installed? Does it help if you add `debugger.async.jdi=false` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I don't have JRebel installed. Doing debugger.async.jdi=false didn't help. But as mentioned downgrading my IDEA was the only thing that worked.

Comment: You may want to report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with more details so that we can fix this issue.