# Caching Warning : The configured limit of 1,000 object was reached while attempting to calculate size of the object graph

Tags: spring-boot, caching

**I am getting following warning when i am trying to run caching job in SpringBoot.**

```
The configured limit of 1,000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph. This can be avoided by adding stop points with @IgnoreSizeOf annotations. Since the CacheManger or Cache <sizeOfPolicy> elements maxDepthExceededBehavior is set to "abort", the sizing operation has stopped and the reported cache size is not accurate. If performance degradation is NOT an issue at the configured limit, raise the limit value using the CacheManager or Cache <sizeOfPolicy> elements maxDepth attribute. For more information, see the Ehcache configuration documentation.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074727/the-configured-limit-of-1-000-object-references-was-reached-while-attempting-to